# Compile Assembly OSX (10.6.8)

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler

I've decided to learn some assembly, however I haven't been able to figure out how to actually assemble it. I'm running OSX 10.6.8 with developer tools installed. I'm running Xcode 3.13, there's no downloads tab in the preferences in the version that I see and the download for command line tools from Apple's site doesn't run on anything less than 10.7.

I've seen some online sources saying that I should use the "as" "gas" or "gcc" commands, however terminal tells me that none of those commands exist. (to test, I simply opened a new terminal window and entered the command name with no parameters. I assume that would work but I could be mistaken.) I can't find any concrete documentation about whether or not this stuff is installed with developer tools/how to check if it is installed/where to install it.

Asking this question here was my last resort, however I'm sure the information was already out there and I just couldn't find it so if anyone could:

- Explain why these commands don't work/what I should install if I want to assemble some basic assembly

  Tell me how I could have figured this out on my own

I'd be really grateful. Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]There is a file named "as" in the Developer/usr/bin/ folder so I'm not sure why the command is not found. Do I have to do more than just navigate to the directory of the file I'm assembling and type "as filename"?

Comment: (Strictly speaking, you don't *compile* assembly code. You *assemble* it.)

Comment: Thanks I was wondering about that, it didn't make much sense that you'd have to compile it. Edited the question just to be more correct.

Comment: As @Nicholas Riley and I pointed out, the command is not run because `/Developer/usr/bin/` is not in your `$PATH`.  Add it to `$PATH`, or re-install Xcode, or call the assembler as `/Developer/usr/bin/as` or add a symlink, or add an alias, or ...

Comment: Thanks, just figured it out. I wasn't aware of how the commands were found with $PATH that's good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to check "UNIX development" when you installed Xcode.  (How were you supposed to know this at the time?)

You can re-install Xcode, making sure to check that magic box.

However, the command-line drivers *are* actually present, they're just not in your path (they're in `/Developer/usr/bin`, if I remember right, though it's been a long time since I've tinkered around with Xcode 3.x).  So you should be able to add that to `$PATH` and use them.

As a third alternative, you can always download a distribution of either `gcc` or `clang`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried reinstalling, but the option for "UNIX Development" was grayed out as if I had already installed it so I added one line to the .profile file in my home folder and the as command now works. For anyone else having this problem, here's what I added: export PATH=/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the Xcode "Command Line Tools" additional download installed. It's available in the Downloads tab of the Xcode preferences window.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have Xcode version 3.1.3. There's no downloads tab (in preferences at least,) and the download that I found for the command line tools on the apple developer site doesn't run on anything less than 10.7. Updated the question.

Comment: Do you know how to check whether or not command line tools is installed? Because if that is indeed the problem then it's just a matter of finding out how to get the version compatible with my computer.

Comment: If you're getting "command not found" when trying to run gcc, you don't have the command-line tools installed. I'm afraid that I don't know offhand where to get them for Snow Leopard, though -- sorry.

Comment: The command line tools are installed in `/Developer` by default in Xcode 3.x.  If you want a copy in `/usr` as well, I seem to remember that they're a separate option in the Xcode installer (you can rerun the installer for the same version of Xcode).  Or you can just add `/Developer/usr/bin` to your PATH; it contains several assemblers.

Comment: Thanks, adding it to $PATH did it.